# Creating multiple circles using svg only shows one circle

Tags: svg, geometry

I am attempting to loop through a variable number of objects and create svg circles using the x/y coordinates associated with them (they are different coordinates). When the page renders I see quick flashes of the circles drawn and then only one. Here is my code:

```
        var parsed_payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload.substring(payload.indexOf("{",0))));
        var m = new Map();
        if (sessionStorage.getItem['customers'] != null){
            m = sessionStorage.getItem['customers'];
        }

        var key = getKey(parsed_payload);           
        //Delete from map if the customer has left the store
        if ( topic=="customerexit") {
            m.delete(key)
        }else{
            m.set(key,parsed_payload);
        }

        sessionStorage.setItem('customers', m);

        document.body.innerHTML = '';

        var svg1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
        svg1.setAttribute("height",1000);
        svg1.setAttribute("width",500);
        document.body.appendChild(svg1);

        m.forEach(function (item, key, mapObj) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
            var x = getX(obj);
            var y = getY(obj);

            var circles = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
            circles.setAttribute("cx",Number(x));
            circles.setAttribute("cy",Number(y));
            circles.setAttribute("r",3);
            circles.setAttribute("fill","red");
            svg1.appendChild(circles);

        });      

    }
```

I'm sure I am missing something obvious here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ted

Comment: The actual generation of the SVG and circle elements looks okay to me.  It is probably something in the rest of the code.  But it's hard to tell because you have left out important functions.  Perhaps you could update your sample to a working snippet with some hardcoded JSON?

Comment: Flagging for: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for taking a look Paul. I found my issue. I was creating a map and storing on sessionStorage, but it was coming back null (since storageSession only stores strings) and my map was always getting re-created which is why I only had one circle drawn each time.

Thanks again,
Ted